# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry is inactive): [PricebookEntryId]

Tags: apex, pricebook, pricebookentry

Can't wrap my head around this error. Any ideas?

```
@isTest
public class RemoveProductFamilyTriggerTest{

static testMethod void RemoveProductFamilyTriggerTestmethod()
{
    Date cd = date.parse('10/10/2018');
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    o.Name='opp1';
    o.CloseDate=cd;
    o.StageName='Needs Analysis';
    o.Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    insert o;
    Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2(
        Name='Testbook');
        insert pb;
    Product2 p1 = new Product2();
        p1.Name='product1';
        p1.Family='Card Present';
        insert p1;
    Quote q1 = new Quote();
        q1.Name='Quote 1';
        q1.OpportunityId=o.id;
        insert q1;
    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
        pbe.Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId();
        pbe.Product2Id=p1.id;
        pbe.UnitPrice=3000;
        pbe.UseStandardPrice=false;
        insert pbe;
    OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
        oli.Quantity=1;
        oli.UnitPrice=100;
        oli.OpportunityId=o.id;
        oli.PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id;
        insert oli;
    QuoteLineItem oli1 = new QuoteLineItem();
        //oli1.PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id;
        oli1.QuoteId = q1.Id;
        oli1.UnitPrice = 200;
        oli1.OpportunityLineItemId=oli.id;
    Test.startTest();
        insert oli1;
    Test.stopTest();
    //insert oli2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to make the pricebook entry Active
In the part

```
    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
    pbe.Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    pbe.Product2Id=p1.id;
    pbe.UnitPrice=3000;
    pbe.UseStandardPrice=false;
    pbe.isActive=true;//Add this line
    insert pbe;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the IsActive flag to true on your Pricebook2, PricebookEntry, and Product2 records. The default value is to make these records inactive.

Comment: I could not even update it with everything active, really strange. from the 150, 125 records fail just like Salesforce is in an existential way